# arm_rfft_init_q31: how is the cfft member initialized?

Tags: c, arm, signal-processing, cortex-m, cmsis

Trying to use some old code with a current CMSIS DSP library. Old code:

```
const unsiged fftlen=128;
arm_cfft_radix4_instance_q31 forward_cfft_instance = {0};
arm_rfft_instance_q31 forward_rfft_instance = {0};
arm_rfft_init_q31(&forward_rfft_instance, &forward_cfft_instance,fftlen, 0, 1);
```

The compiler tells me that the function arm_rfft_init_q31 does not accept my 2nd parameter, `(_cfft_)`, anymore, in the current version of the DSP lib.

Since the rfft struct still has a pointer to a cfft instance, I wonder how this pointer is initialized these days?

I tried to find a relevant changelog entry that explains this to me, so far without luck.

Comment: @Olaf how is that related to the OP's problem?

Comment: @fluter: Point taken. No Idea why I read the last line as an initialiser for a `struct`. Maybe I need new glasses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source (I did not know it was available) I find that the initialization function inserts a pointer to a global constant cfft struct that is apparently linked into the binary as needed.

Answer (score 2):

The function is declared as

```
arm_status  arm_rfft_init_q31 (arm_rfft_instance_q31 *S, uint32_t fftLenReal, uint32_t ifftFlagR, uint32_t bitReverseFlag);
```

It expect an `uint32_t` as the second argument, while you are passing a pointer to a `arm_cfft_radix4_instance_q31`. Also, according to the name, what you want is just:

```
uint32_t fftlen=128;
arm_rfft_instance_q31 forward_rfft_instance = {0};
arm_rfft_init_q31(&forward_rfft_instance, fftlen, 0, 1);
```

Comment: Yes, the function is declared like that now. In 2012, the function took 5 arguments, the second was this pointer to th cfft thing. Reasoning was, the fft for real inputs was using the fft for complex inputs internally with some clever reorganization of data. The rfft_init function was initializing both structures. Since the current library's rfft structure still has a cfft pointer member (the last member), I wonder how this cfft is allocated. After all, on cortex m, the library cannot simply call malloc.

Answer (score 0):

I had seen code on github for CMSIS 5, but I can't find it now. It confirmed what you'd seen about global constant cfft structs being available in the math library.

Use nm to look at the library, libarm_cortexM4lf_math.a in my case:

```
nm libarm_cortexM4lf_math.a
```

This provides a list of read-only structs that are referenced in the arm_rfft_init_q31 call.

```
arm_const_structs.o:
00000000 R arm_cfft_sR_f32_len1024
00000000 R arm_cfft_sR_f32_len128
00000000 R arm_cfft_sR_f32_len16
00000000 R arm_cfft_sR_f32_len2048
00000000 R arm_cfft_sR_f32_len256
00000000 R arm_cfft_sR_f32_len32
00000000 R arm_cfft_sR_f32_len4096
00000000 R arm_cfft_sR_f32_len512
00000000 R arm_cfft_sR_f32_len64
00000000 R arm_cfft_sR_q15_len1024
00000000 R arm_cfft_sR_q15_len128
00000000 R arm_cfft_sR_q15_len16
00000000 R arm_cfft_sR_q15_len2048
00000000 R arm_cfft_sR_q15_len256
00000000 R arm_cfft_sR_q15_len32
00000000 R arm_cfft_sR_q15_len4096
00000000 R arm_cfft_sR_q15_len512
00000000 R arm_cfft_sR_q15_len64
00000000 R arm_cfft_sR_q31_len1024
00000000 R arm_cfft_sR_q31_len128
00000000 R arm_cfft_sR_q31_len16
00000000 R arm_cfft_sR_q31_len2048
00000000 R arm_cfft_sR_q31_len256
00000000 R arm_cfft_sR_q31_len32
00000000 R arm_cfft_sR_q31_len4096
00000000 R arm_cfft_sR_q31_len512
00000000 R arm_cfft_sR_q31_len64
```

And the q31 initialisation, for example:

```
arm_rfft_init_q31.o:
         U arm_cfft_sR_q31_len1024
         U arm_cfft_sR_q31_len128
         U arm_cfft_sR_q31_len16
         U arm_cfft_sR_q31_len2048
         U arm_cfft_sR_q31_len256
         U arm_cfft_sR_q31_len32
         U arm_cfft_sR_q31_len4096
         U arm_cfft_sR_q31_len512
         U arm_cfft_sR_q31_len64
00000001 T arm_rfft_init_q31
000000e4 t $d
00000000 r $d
00000000 r $d
00000010 N $d
00000000 r realCoefAQ31
00000000 r realCoefBQ31
00000000 t $t
```

Instead of using the init functions for Real FFTs, the instance structure can be defined directly referencing the cfft structs above as well as the twiddle factor pointers, as indicated in the [CMSIS documentation](https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/DSP/html/group__Fast.html).